# Why .map() produces two different output?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

Why does .map(() => x + 3) vs .map((x) => x +3) produces two different results?

See code snippet below. I have the following code **app.component.ts**

```
obs = Observable.of(1, 2, 3, 4);

ngOnInit() {
    this.usingMapToMakeInnerObservable();
}

usingMapToMakeInnerObservable() {
    this.obs
        .map(x => Observable.timer(500).map(() => x + 3)) // A. Output 4, 5, 6, 7
        //.map(x => Observable.timer(500).map((x) => x + 3)) // B. Output 3, 3, 3, 3
        .subscribe(
            x => console.log(x),
            err => console.error(err),
            () => console.log('done completed')
        );
}
```

Comment: you should learn about scope and closure as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 1st Case

```
.map(x => //here x value can be `1, 2, 3, 4`
   Observable.timer(500).map(() => x + 3) // x will hold from last map
)
```

In above code first x can hold values `1, 2, 3, 4`, then we applied [**`Observable.timer`**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/timer.md). Afterwards in `.map` x will have current item of array.

Where as in 2nd Case

```
.map(x =>  //here x value can be `1, 2, 3, 4`
   Observable.timer(500).map((x) => x + 3) //x here it has own x so
)
```

In above code 1st map x value can hold `1, 2, 3, 4` values. When we declare `x` for `timer` Observable. Now `x` will no longer the parent map's `x` value. So then you must be thing why it constantly `Output: 3,3,3,3`. The reason is when we don't mention any other parameters to `timer`(Observable) it returns `0` every-time.